# Where is the location of the sql lite database in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, ios-simulator

I'm trying to find the sql lite database as used the Iphone simulator under Xcode 8. This is the path I'm looking in:

```
Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4E8D17D7-BA66-4FED-8A4A-0AF7CCE6DFB7/data/Containers/Data/Application/9C5D7B38-D014-4CD9-A75B-7C6343A1E096/Documents
```

I can see other files I've created but can't see any sql lite databases. I'm using core data and have been saving a retrieving records. How can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you got a **container** like this :

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "HitList")
```

Now in the **AppDelegate** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** print this code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let directory = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
let url = directory.appendingPathComponent("HitList" + ".sqlite")
print("My SQL Location")
print (url)

return true
}
```

You will find the **path** of the **sqlite**. If you find it difficult to search it press **command+space** for spotlight search, type **~/Library** in the spotlight search, you will unlock the library which is usually hidden. Then follow the path you get from **xcode**. Hope that helps.